# Show that the points A, O, D are collinear iff triangle ABC is isosceles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> Let D be a point of the segment (BC). On the same side of the line BC we construct the isosceles triangles FDC and EBD, with FD = FC and EB = ED. We denote by O the middle of the segment EF and by A the intersection of the lines CF and BE. Show that the points A, O, D are collinear if and only if the triangle ABC is isosceles.

**My idea:**
I'm also going to put a photo below where I am going to show more exactly every idea I had.
I went if ABC is isosceles I should demonstrate that A,O, D are collinear...I demonstrated it. (You can look in the picture below)
Now I went backwards,if A,O,D. I dont know how I should demonstrate it. I thought of doing congruante triangles, but I dont find an angle or another line. I should demonstarte that AEDF is paralelogram.

[image]

[image]

Thank you so much! Hope one of you can help me! Any idea is welcome!

Comment: You could try to show that if $ABC$ is not isosceles then $AOD$ are not collinear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the points $A$, $O$, $D$ are collinear:

Let $\angle BDE =\angle DBE = \alpha$ and  $\angle CDF =\angle DCF = \beta$. Then $\angle EDF$ and $\angle EAF$ are both equal to $180^\circ - \alpha -\beta$. Now rotate triangle EDF through $180^\circ$ about $O$. Then $F$ maps to $E$, $E$ maps to $F$ and $D$ maps onto the line $OA$ - but because $\angle EDF=\angle EAF$ it must map onto $A$ itself. So $AEDF$ is a parallelogram and so $|AF|=|ED|=|EB|$ and $|AE|=|FD|=|FC|$. Thus $|AB| = |AE| +|EB| = |FC| + |AF| = |AC|$ as required.

If triangle $ABC$ is isosceles, then it is relatively easy to show that $A$, $O$, $D$ are collinear.

Comment: Let me know if you would like more detail.

Comment: what does maps means?

Comment: If a function or transformation or function takes input $a$ to output $b$, you can say that the function or transformation *maps* $a$ *onto* $b$. Here "$F$ maps to $E$" means that $F$ is moved to the position of $E$ by the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible alternative (blind, analytic) solution, but consider accepting the solution of [mcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1059789/mcd) first. We introduce algebra and work straightforward.

Let us denote by $E',O',A',F'$ the projections of the points $E,O,A,F$ on $BC$. Denote by $h_E$, $h_O$, $h_A$, $h_F$ the (lengths of the) segments
$EE'$, $OO'$, $AA'$, $FF'$. Also let $x$ be $BE'=E'D$, and $y=DF'=F'C$, and $a= DA'$. We may and do assume that $x\le y$ (else reflect $D$ on $BC$ w.r.t. its mid point).

[image: Geometry problem solved analytically, MSE 4616947]

We consider the above situation with $a, h_A$ seen as unknowns.
Then two equation in these two unknowns are immediately written:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\frac {2x+a}{h_A} &=\frac{BA'}{AA'}=\frac{BE'}{EE'}=\frac x{h_E}\ ,\\
\frac {2y-a}{h_A} &=\frac{CA'}{AA'}=\frac{CF'}{FF'}=\frac y{h_F}\ ,
\end{aligned}
\right.
\qquad
\text{ with solution }
\qquad
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
a   &= \frac{2xy(h_F-h_E)}{yh_E+xh_F}\ ,\\
h_A &= \frac{2h_Eh_F(x+y)}{yh_E+xh_F}\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
We need only
$$
\frac{a}{h_A}=\frac{xy/(x+y)}{h_Eh_F/(h_F-h_E)}
\ .
$$
Now the points $O,A,D$ are collinear, if( and only i)f we have the proportionality $DA':AA' =AO':OO'$. This means:
$$
\frac{xy/(x+y)}{h_Eh_F/(h_F-h_E)}
=
\frac{(y-x)/2}{(h_E+h_F)/2}
\qquad
\text{ i.e. }
\qquad
\underbrace{\frac yx-\frac xy}_{(y^2-x^2)/(xy)}
=
\underbrace{\frac{h_F}{h_E}
-
\frac{h_E}{h_F}}
_{(h_F^2-h_E^2)/(h_Eh_F)}
\ .
$$
Since the function $\displaystyle t\to t-\frac 1t$ is injective (strictly increasing), we obtain equivalently $y:x =h_F:h_E$.

So $O,A,D$ are collinear, iff $y:x =h_F:h_E$, iff $\Delta BEE'\sim\Delta CFF'$, iff $\hat B=\hat C$, iff $\Delta ABC$ is isosceles **in $\bf A$**.

$\square$